# Question about the relationship between Weak Axiom and Slutsky Matrix

Tags: microeconomics, preferences, walrasian, demand, slutsky-equation

We know that if a differentiable Walrasian demand function $x(p,w)$ satisfies Walras' law ($p^Tx=w$), homogeneity of degree zero ($x(\alpha p,\alpha w)=x(p,w)$), and the weak axiom of revealed preference, then at any $(p,w)$, the Slutsky matrix
\begin{equation}
S(p,w)=D_px(p,w)+D_wx(p,w)x(p,w)^T
\end{equation}
is negative semidefinite.

**My question** is: if $S(p,w)$ is negative semidefinite, then what can we say about the demand function $x(p,w)$? Can we conclude that $x(p,w)$ satisfies weak axiom?

Answer (score 2):

It is almost true.

There are examples of demand that have a negative definite Slutsky matrix but fails the Weak Axiom.

However, if we ask that
$$v \cdot S(p,w) v <0 $$
whenever $v \not = \alpha p$ for any scalar $\alpha$ (i.e. $S$ is negative definite for all vectors except those proportional to price), then the Weak Axiom holds.

Comment: I see. Is that a stronger condition than negaive semidifinite? 
 Because it could be the case that vS(p,w)v=0 for some v that is not porpotional to p when S(p,w) is negaive semidifinite.

Comment: @Huaixin You're correct. If we weaken negative definite to negative semidefinite, again we can obtain an example that fails the Weak Axiom. It does however satisfy a weaker Weak Axiom. This result is by Kihlstrom, Mas-Colell and Sonnenschien (1976), they call it WWA (if you're interested).

Comment: get it, thanks for the precise answer.